# Limit the simultaneous requests served by the ASP.NET Web API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I'm using ASP.NET Web API 2.2 along with Owin to build a web service and I observed each call to the controller will be served by a separate thread running on the server side, that's nothing surprising and is the behavior I expected.

One issue I'm having now is that because the server side actions are very memory intense so if more than X number of users are calling in at the same time there is a good chance the server code will throw an out-of-memory exception.

Is it possible to set a global "maximum action count" so that Web Api can queue (not reject) the incoming calls and only proceed when there's an empty slot.

I can't run the web service in 64bit because some of the referenced libraries won't support that.

I also looked at libraries like https://github.com/stefanprodan/WebApiThrottle but it can only throttle based on the frequency of calls.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add a piece of `OwinMiddleware` along these lines (influenced by the WebApiThrottle you linked to):

```
public class MaxConccurrentMiddleware : OwinMiddleware
{
    private readonly int maxConcurrentRequests;
    private int currentRequestCount;

    public MaxConccurrentMiddleware(int maxConcurrentRequests)
    {
        this.maxConcurrentRequests = maxConcurrentRequests;
    }

    public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Interlocked.Increment(ref currentRequestCount) > maxConcurrentRequests)
            {
                var response = context.Response;

                response.OnSendingHeaders(state =>
                {
                    var resp = (OwinResponse)state;
                    resp.StatusCode = 429; // 429 Too Many Requests
                }, response);

                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }

            await Next.Invoke(context);
        }
        finally
        {
            Interlocked.Decrement(ref currentRequestCount);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, what's the appropriate way to place the OwinMiddleware correctly in the Owin pipeline, I tried using app.use<MaxConccurrentMiddleware> in the StartUp but then the concurrency check were only triggered after the request was completed, so the response had all the normal content but with the response code set to 429

Comment: Ahh..I think I get it now...I forgot to return in the case when maxConcurrentRequests is breached so it's always invoking the next activity in the pipeline

Comment: 429 or 503? Too many requests 429 status code is relevent when it is from the same origin right? I think, 503 service unavailable suits this case. :P

Comment: app.Use<MaxConcurrentMiddleware>(Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConcurrentRequests"]));